# Document sharing without letting the user download the file.

Tags: node.js, mongodb, reactjs, express, encryption

I want to share PDF between 2 people without letting the user2 download it. Scenario is:

1, User has a document which he wants to share with user2.

2, User 1 chooses the file to share from its computer and encrypts the document and then upload the encrypted document so that only encrypted document lives on server.-

Question -Which DB shall i use to save the encrypted document?

What will be the data type to save the encrypted document?

Can I use mongo DB?

3, User 2 wants to see the file so get decryption key from user 1.

4, User 2 connects to server and get encrypted document and decrypt it and read on viewer.

Question - Which viewer library to use?

Comment: It will never work. If user2 is able to view the file, he will also be able to download the file.

Comment: I see some application like https://www.scribd.com/ which does this. I wander how they do that/

Comment: Search on Google, you will find many tricks to download scribd documents.

Comment: yeah you are right @Aminadav ...Do you know any way to make it something like Teamviewer..where user2 comes to server reads the file and does not get to download it.

Comment: The user will always be able to do a screenshot. If you don't have a problem with screenshots, serve the document as image (convert the PDF to image, and serve it to the user2)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are getting confused. If user2 can read the decrypted file, he already has the file. You can't stop him from downloading it.

As far as the choice of DB is concerned, I would suggest you to store the file in some storage (filesystem, or datastore like AWS S3) and save the link of the file in the DB.

So if user2 requests the file, you can give him the signed URL to the file.